# put method is updating the database but not uploading the image and changing the image name

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have this problem that is not causing any error, but it's not doing what it should.

**I have this code in my controller.**

```
const updateEvent = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const event = await EventModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.idEvent,
      req.body,
      { new: true }
    );

    return res.status(200).json(event);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in updating event:", error);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
  }
};
```

this is the call out in my eventRouter

```
const eventController = require("../Controllers/event");
const config = require("../Config/config");
const upload = require("../upload");
// http://localhost:9091/Event/updateEvent/idEvent
eventRouter.put(
  "/updateEvent/:idEvent",
  upload.single("image"),
  eventController.updateEvent
);
```

I'm using Multer, which is the upload file for the image upload.

```
const multer = require("multer");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "./Images/Uploads");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(
      null,
      new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, "-") +
        "-" +
        path.extname(file.originalname)
    );
  },
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  console.log(file.mimetype);
  const allowedMimes = ["image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png", "image/gif"];

  if (allowedMimes.includes(file.mimetype)) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(new Error("File extension must be jpeg, jfif, jpg ou png"), null, false);
  }
};

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5, // 5MB limit
  },
  fileFilter: fileFilter,
});

module.exports = upload;
```

I also make sure to use the body-parser in the index.js because I'm using the form-data

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Is there another approach I can take to ensure that the event image and the data passed in the request are being both updated simultaneously because I've seen other questions in stack but they were all related to body-parser.
Any help or suggestion is appreciated!